# get full html source code of page through ajax request through javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

The javascript code will be launched from www.example.com through the url bar in google chrome so i cannot make use of jquery. My goal is to pass the full html source code of www.example.com/page.html to a variable in javascript when i launch the code in www.example.com. Is this possible? If so how? I know to get the current page source it's just `document.documentElement.outerHTML` but i'm not sure how i'd do this. I think it's possible by using `responseText` somewhere in the following code:

```
http.send(params);
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.example.com/page.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: you were almost there

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
data = ""
url = "http://www.example.com/page.html"
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4){
    data = xhr.responseText
    }
}
xhr.send();

function process(){
    url = "http://www.example.com/page.html"
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4){
        alert(xhr.responseText)
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

this is how i run script from the address bar.. I do it all the time.. 
i create a bookmark like this 
`javascript:script=document.createElement('script');script.src='http://10.0.0.11/clear.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); void(sss=1);`

then i host the js file on my computer.. i use analogx simpleserver... then you can use a full page for your script

Comment: I place it like this:javascript:codegoeshere. Have you verified this works?

Comment: so you are running it from a js file now?

Comment: Can you modify it so it doesn't work with functions and so it doesn't alert?

Comment: The variable data now seems to be empty, i cannot alert it even.

Comment: Can you restore the code back to the original one? Your modification really messed it up, it doesn't work at all.